# Computing MD5 value returns "0001..0E0F" for different strings

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I am trying to get an MD5 hash of two different lists so I can easily tell if the lists are the same or different. However, I keep getting the same MD5 hash for both lists even though they have different contents.

Hash1: 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F

Hash2: 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F

They should be different because the contents of the list are different, right?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var md5Hash = MD5.Create();
            var list1 = new List<string> { "1", "dog", "cat", "mouse" };
            var list2 = new List<string> { "2", "dog", "cat", "mouse"};
            var md5 = new Md5Hash();
            var joined1 = string.Join(",", list1.ToArray());
            var joined2 = string.Join(",", list2.ToArray());
            var hash1 = md5.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, joined1);
            Console.WriteLine("hash 1: {0}", hash1);
            var hash2 = md5.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, joined2);
            Console.WriteLine("hash 2: {0}", hash2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

I suspect the problem is with the method that is generating the Md5hash...

```
internal string GetMd5Hash(HashAlgorithm md5Hash, string input)
        {
            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash. 
            var data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes 
            // and create a string.
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 

            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(i.ToString("X2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string. 
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

The `var data` variable does return different data between the two lists but the method returns the same string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
stringBuilder.Append(i.ToString("X2"));
```

That's just giving you the hex value of the *array index* `i` you're using, and is the reason why your MD5s seem so ... "planned" (sequential numbers from 0x00 to 0x0f).

You need something like:

```
stringBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("X2"));
```

to get the *value in the hash* at position `i`.

Answer (score 6):

> 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F

Note how these are the numbers 00 to 0F, in order.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(i.ToString("X2"));
}
```

You’re appending `i` in hexadecimal, which iterates from 00 to 0F. `data[i]` would probably work better.